# PrimeNG p-dataView with not repeating FieldSet

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-datatable

I am using p-dataView and I would like to use p-fieldset depending on the application type and I would like to find a way for the fieldset not to be repeated. Below is just one case, I will ending up with multiple fieldsSet. Not sure what will be the most efficient way to do this? Basically, I am trying to group certain rows to gather under one fieldset.

**for example:**

```
<p-dataView [value]="someobject" [paginator]="true" [rows]="20">

    <ng-template let-prev let-rowIndexValue="rowIndex" pTemplate="listItem">

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <p-fieldset class="fieldset-auto-width" *ngIf="prev.app_type == 10">
                <p-header style="width:30px">Apps</p-header>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="cbPreviewID" checked name="cbxPreview" (click)="togglePreviewApp($event,rowIndexValue)" style="margin-right:5px;margin-bottom:10px;margin-left:5px; margin-top:10px" [value]='prev.app_id'> {{prev.app_name}}
                    </div>

                    <div *ngIf="prev.roles.length>1" class="col-md-3" style="margin-right:5px;margin-bottom:10px;margin-left:5px; margin-top:10px">

                    <b>Role:</b> 
                    <select name="role" (ngModelChange)="selectedPreviewAppRole($event,rowIndexValue)" class="dropdown" style="width:85%" required [(ngModel)]="prev.seletedAppRoleID">
                        <option class="dropdown-item" value="" selected>Select</option>
                        <option class="dropdown-item" *ngFor='let role of prev.roles' [ngValue]="role.app_role_id">
                            {{role.app_role_name}}
                        </option>
                    </select>

                </p-fieldset>
            </div>  
        </div>                      
    </ng-template>                      
</p-dataView>
```

for example test 1 & 2 should be under 1 field set called because their(prev.app_type == 10")

Now I get :
[image]

Looking for:
[image]

Comment: its due to *ngIf="prev.app_type == 10"?. can you try removing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]Tried including p-fieldset inside p-dataview. It's working as expected. might be issue with *ngIf condition.

**Component:**

```
cars = [{
    id: 1,
    items: [{
      name: 'car1',
      description: 'this is car1 description'
    },{
      name: 'car2',
      description: 'this is car2 description'
    },{
      name: 'car3',
      description: 'this is car3 description'
    },{
      name: 'car4',
      description: 'this is car4 description'
    },{
      name: 'car5',
      description: 'this is car5 description'
    }]
```

}];

**Template:**

```
<p-dataView [value]="cars" [paginator]="true" [rows]="5">
  <p-header>List of Cars</p-header>
  <p-footer>Choose from the list.</p-footer>
  <ng-template let-car pTemplate="listItem">
      <p-fieldset legend="Header" *ngIf="car.id === 1" [toggleable]="true">
          <div *ngFor="let _car of car.items">
              {{_car.name}} - {{_car.description}}
          </div>
      </p-fieldset>
  </ng-template>
</p-dataView>
```

Refer the attached screenshot.

Comment: I was able to achieve the same thing but the issue is there, taking your example, I want for example to have car 1 and car 2 under one feild set and the rest under one fieldset

Comment: I don't want to repeat the field-set for every record so I do want to fiter my records using *ngIf="prev.app_type == 10" , so if the id is 10 then all apps with 10 should be under one fieldset..same for if 11 etc....

Comment: any ideas anyone !

Comment: can you please create stackblitz. will take a look.

Comment: I can't, and this is the issue :) ...i updated my above code by adding a screenshot

Comment: also both apps have the same type id, did it help?

Comment: As per the code, it will display in 2 fieldset bcz both have value 10. Instead of looping array of object. You need to form an array with apptype and their corresponding children. [{appType: 10, children: [{name: 'text1'},{name: 'text2'} ]]

Comment: Updated the answer. please check.

Comment: so sorry for the really delayed response, this works